# Logic operation on Karnaugh Maps?

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map, reference-materials

**Question:**

Normally I find Karnaugh Map of an expression from its truth table, but can we have Logic operation on two Karnaugh Maps ?

[image]

---

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: I didn't read carefully over everything. Seems like there should be a rigourous way to do it. I'm personally more interested in the case where your two karnaugh maps have different numbers of inputs.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think this would also work, for example 2 inputs and 1 input, then we get a 2 by 4 K-Map

Comment: It should work, but it seems to be a lot of work.  I'd find it easier to populate the truth table **and** then populate the kmap.